# sweepGradient end point is not animating

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to animate Sweep gradient angle, so that i can achieve moving colour effect.

I set start angle to 0 and animating that angle to 2*math.pi. whereas i am stating end angle at 2*math.pi and animating it to 4*math.pi;

When i do so, start angle is animating but end angle is not animating.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

class Delete extends StatefulWidget {
  Delete({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _DeleteState createState() => _DeleteState();
}

class _DeleteState extends State<Delete> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<double> _animation;
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 5));
    _animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 2 * math.pi).animate(_controller)
      ..addListener(() {
        print(_animation.value);

        setState(() {});
      });

    _controller.repeat();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('hello'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: 180,
        height: 180,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          gradient: SweepGradient(
            colors: [
              Colors.blue,
              Colors.green,
              Colors.yellow,
              Colors.red,
              Colors.blue
            ],
            //  stops: [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1],
            center: Alignment(-0.35, -0.35),
            startAngle: _animation.value,
            endAngle: _animation.value + (2 * math.pi),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, and it should be. to cover whole circle.

Comment: add it to `build()` method `return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        key: GlobalKey(),
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          gradient: SweepGradient(
            colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.green, Colors.yellow, Colors.red, Colors.blue],
            transform: GradientRotation(value * 2 * pi),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ),
    Slider(value: value, onChanged: (v) => setState(() => value = v),),
  ],
);`

Comment: what does value variable mean ? (_animation.value ?? ) because we can not assign any value to it?

Comment: a field inside `_DeleteState` class: `double value = 0.0;`

Comment: here, the problem is that my center point is at not center, so i can not use transform. or is their any why to rotate it from my new offset ?

Comment: check the sources - i found `transform` 20 minutes ago too as i did not know about it before i saw the sources

Comment: yes, their is a transom property, but it rotate from center and i want to rotate from gradient origin.

Comment: i check out sources code, but didn’t get any idea.

Comment: `_animation.value` is the interpolated value over time ... so basically when you are going from 0 to 5 in 5 seconds the `_animtaion.value` will go up by one in exactly 1 second.

Comment: I have adde a working solution for your problem! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have done it right.

What you were missing (and it is not exactly well explained in the docs) is that you need to set a `TileMode` on your `SweepGradient` to get your expected result.

Here is a working example:

```dart
class Delete extends StatefulWidget {
  Delete({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DeleteState createState() => _DeleteState();
}

class _DeleteState extends State<Delete> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<double> _animation;
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 5));
    _animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 2 * math.pi).animate(_controller)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });

    _controller.repeat();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('hello'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        width: 180,
        height: 180,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          gradient: SweepGradient(
            colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.green, Colors.yellow, Colors.red, Colors.blue],
//              stops: [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1],
            center: Alignment(-0.35, -0.35),
            startAngle: _animation.value,
            endAngle: _animation.value + (2 * math.pi),
            tileMode: TileMode.repeated,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can find the docs for the `TileMode` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/TileMode-class.html).

Comment: Thank You. That’s what i was looking for.